# regex four digit validation, validating digit one by one

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, validation

i have some code for validation phone number with prefix validation. i want to validate from first digit and so on up to four digits. example:

first digit
0 => valid 
1-9 => invalid

second digit
8 => valid 
1-7 & 9 => invalid

third digit
1 => valid
2 => valid
3-9 => invalid

four digit
7 => valid
8 => valid
9 => valid
1-6 => invalid

is it possible to validating like that with regex?

i have regex code

```
/^08(17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)[0-9]{0,8}$/
```

but not validating from first digit. please help me

Here's my php code:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div style="width:601px; height: 487px;position: fixed;">
            <div style="background-image: url(xlimages/20160614_XL_elemenVisual_-02_cropped.png); background-size: 600px 563px;">
            <div style="height:563px;">
                <center>
<h2 style="color: white; padding-top: 32px; font-size: 50px; font-family: "Gotham Bold";"><b>Masukkan No. XL/Axis</b></h2>
                        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>" method="POST">
                            <div style="margin-top:70px;">
                                <div class="input-control">
                                    <br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="msidn" id="jkeyboard" onlick="$('#pwd').replaceSelection("", true);" min="1" style="font-weight: bold; width:500px; height: 70px; border-color:#1ba1e2; color: #1ba1e2; font-size: 30px; text-align: center; line-height: 75px;" required>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cek"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><span id="spnPhoneStatus"></span>
                                <div style="margin-top: 190px;"><b>
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();" name="sbm" value="Lanjut" style="margin-bottom: 6px;background: #1ba1e2; border-color: #1ba1e2; height: 70px; font-weight: bold;  margin-left:0px; width:280px; font-size: 30px;" class="button primary">
                                </b><br/><br/><br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jkeyboard').blur(function(e) {
    if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Nomor Yang Anda Masukkan No. XL/Axis');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Nomor Yang Anda Masukkan Bukan No. XL/Axis');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});

function validatePhone(jkeyboard) {
  var a = document.getElementById(jkeyboard).value;
  var filter = /^08(17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)[0-9]{0,8}$/;
  if (filter.test(a)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Add code to show the efforts taken by you to solve your problem.

Comment: What do you mean that your regex is not validating from first digit?

Comment: @ShyamBhimani oke wait i will edit my post

Comment: @MariaDeleva i mean with that regex i can't validating number for first digit. i have phone number 0817565656 i will validate from 1-4 digit, when i put first or second or third digit example 0 and 8 and 1 will show invalid, but when i put 0817 is valid. what I want is to validate what prefix number from the first digit

Comment: `/^08?(17|18|19|31|32|33|38|59|77|78)?[0-9]{0,8}$/` Perhaps making them optional like this? At least it works on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gQ6kS4/1)

Comment: You mean to validate while typing [like this regex?](https://regex101.com/r/zE6xG7/1) But your requirements are not clear. Your regex shows eg as third digit `3` in `33` or `5` in `59` but your rule says for third digit `3-9` invalid. Same with fourth digit.

Comment: @MariaDeleva still don't work, see my post i already updated, i have number 081755555 so the prefix number is 0817, well i will validate 0817 from first digit no way when i type 0817 show valid. when i typed first, second and third digit will show invalid. u know what i mean?

Comment: @bobblebubble yeah that's right, thx you you save my time, how do I give you reputation?

Comment: @Eightleven, so the regex itself was incorrect (i.e., 31, 32, 33, 38,59,77,78 were not valid values for third and fourth digits). 
Then my variant would look like: `^08?[12]?[7-9]?[0-9]{0,8}$`

Comment: @bobblebubble fourth is fine but when i typed further is show invalid. any solution?

Comment: @MariaDeleva, same bro when type first digit is valid but when i type second digit except 8 is valid, must be invalid

Comment: @Eightleven, here is @bobblebubble regex continued: `^0([8]([12]([789]([0-9]{0,8}))?)?)?$`

Comment: @MariaDeleva oh god it's work, thank you. how do i give you reputation?

Comment: Looks like you got it going, glad my input helped (: and plus for @MariaDeleva final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to combined effort of [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)
 and me this is the final regex:

```
^0([8]([12]([789]([0-9]{0,8}))?)?)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

it's solved, thx for bobblebubble, this work regex for my problem 
 `/^0(?:8(?:[12][789]?)?)?$/`